# Wordpress application pwd usage

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to build an app which needs to share users with a wordpress app. I want to use the REST api offered by wordpress and the application password feature. I'm a bit confused on how to proceed.
I will first create a users with permission to create account.
Then do I need to create a application password for each users? and with those password the user will have the same permission as in wordpress ?
Ideally I'ld like to have 1 request to login, 1 to register and 1 to logout.

**Edit :**

There seems to be multiple way to authenticate to wordpress (jwt, Oauth, app pwd). Which wants would fit the best for an mobile app usage. And which provide 3 simple api call like :

- login (email, pwd)
- register (email, username, pwd)
- logout

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/#:~:text=be%20safely%20revoked.-,Authorization%20Flow,-To%20ensure%20that)

Comment: But here in the proposed flow, the user has to authorise the app to log to his account. Is it possible to bypass this step?

Comment: Maybe use Basic Auth Plugin see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#:~:text=There%E2%80%99s%20also%20a,above) and [here](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth)

Comment: But basic auth plugin is said to be safe only over SSL. So I'ld rather not use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using miniOrange plugin on wordpress to set JWT token login. Then for the registration, I created an account with only permission to create users, then I added an application password to this account and I use it to create the accounts.